# Changing FROM in all queries for an ActiveRecord model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a rails project that is connected to a third-party MySQL database **that I cannot change the schema for**.  So far, I've been able to shoe-horn everything into rails and make it play nice, but I've come across an interesting problem.

I have a table, we'll call it `foos`.  I have an ActiveRecord model called `Foo` that uses this table.  The problem is that this table represents two similar but distinct types of record.  We'll call them Foo type A and Foo type B.  To get around this, I've created two classes, `FooTypeA` and `FooTypeB` that inherit from `Foo` and have default scopes so that they only contain records of their respective types.

My code looks something like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  # methods common to both types
end

class FooTypeA < Foo
  default_scope -> { where is_type_a: true }
  # methods for type A
end

class FooTypeB < Foo
  default_scope -> { where is_type_a: false }
  # methods for type B
end
```

For the most part, this works pretty well, except for the fact that sometimes an association chain joins over both of these models.  Since they come from the same table, this causes ambiguity problems, and generates exploding SQL queries.  I've been writing custom join queries to get around this, but it's quickly becoming cumbersome.

I know I can change the default table name for a model with the `self.table_name` value, but is there a way that I can tell rails to change the FROM portion of the SQL query for a model so that I can make all queries from FooTypeA read as: `SELECT foo_as.* FROM foos AS foo_as ...`

I'm open to other suggestions, but this seems like the easiest solution if it's possible.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to split the records into 2 distinct tables and then treat each type of record as a single Model? If you have another application using this database, I guess it won't be possible though...

Comment: tip for Stackoverflow: to format text of your answer into a block of code, select your text and then press Ctrl+k (or prepend each line of code with 4 blank spaces). If you want an inline piece of code, use the backticks `

Comment: I'm afraid I can't change the DB schema.  That was my first impulse as well.  There are other services talking to it that would break.

Comment: What you are doing is STI (Single Table Inheritance) there are some great articles on handling this [Rails 4](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/), [Rails 3](https://projectramon.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/exploring-rails-single-table-inheritance/) but there are many more just google Single table inheritance Rails and tada but to do this correctly you may have to change DB design and then handle the issues by monkey patching for the services

Comment: @engineersmnky, that does look like what I'm doing, but first, I can't change the database schema, and second, unless I missed something, it looks like it still wouldn't resolve the issue of creating an association between the two models.

Comment: One thing you might want to try is: `self.inheritance_column = :is_type_a` on `Foo`. Then on your child models(assuming `:is_type_a` is a column with values like A|B). `def self.sti_name; "A"; end` and `def self.sti_name; "B"; end`

Comment: @JonathanLamothe there is no association between these 2 models at all other than sharing a table and Why should there be when these 2 negate each other? I know you can't change the schema but honestly in this case I feel it would be more maintainable if you did. In that case since you only have A and B. I would simple modularize the shared methods and create 2 tables. I generally only promote STI if there are at least 3 shared objects or the expectation of expanding.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the ActiveRecord .from method solve your problem?

You could also create two views (depending on mysql version) and use those for table sources but unless you *only* read from the tables, you can get into writable view issues which I would try and avoid.